# Handsontable column hiding not working

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have 10 columns (`C1, C2...C10`) in the data array. What I want is to have all the columns in the background but display only C1 to C5 to the user. The reason: In the validations part, I need to have these hidden fields to find whether the values typed in visible columns are valid or not. I am using `javascript` on a button click outside the `handsontable` definition for these validation.

What I did currently is to define the data array with values for ALL 10 columns and while defining the new handsontable statement, used columns [ ] tag to display only the columns to be visible. (In the columns section, I have inserted only C1 to C5 and did not include C6 to C10). Now the problem is that, when In used .getData() to get the dataset, the hidden columns (on other words the columns not included in the columns [ ] tag of the handsontable definition) are coming as undefined, when accessing using

```
var gettablearray = handsontable1.getData();
window.alert(gettablearray[rowindex][columnindex]);
```

Is this is achievable though an existing straight forward official way? Or please advice what could be a work around.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**The nice way**

You can refer to your data array whenever you check any data. Assuming you are enabling sorting, the best way is to use the `sortIndex` method which translates from the view data row to the original data index:

```
physicalIndex = instance.sortIndex[logicalIndex][0];
```

**The ugly way**

Render all 10 columns, then hide columns 6-10. This way you can access all data on the same level.